# Optimize CoffeeScript comparison function

Tags: optimization, coffeescript

I've wrote this CoffeScript function to compare values in a table, but it turned out to be a HUGE function.

Since the code is really really long, you can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/emisfera/394c12af055e0239e2f2) as well.

Code explanation:

The code searches for all the values in a dynamically created datatable and appends the comparison values in another column, Moreover, I had to clone the same statements (because the number of columns is different based on window size) to get it to work on mobile as well.

Is there any way I can reduce the size of this function?

```
  comparekeys = ->
    if $("#keys tbody tr").length > 1 
      $.expr[":"].exactly = (e, i, m) ->
        $(e).text() is m[3]
      $("#keys tbody tr td:nth-child(2):exactly(0)").html ""
      $("#keys tbody tr").each(->
        width = $(window).width()
        if width > 1025
          a = Number($(this).find("td")[1].innerHTML)
          b = Number($(this).find("td")[3].innerHTML)
          c = Number($(this).find("td")[4].innerHTML)
          d = Number($(this).find("td")[5].innerHTML)
          changes = $(this).find("td:eq(2)")
          row1 = $(this).find("td:eq(1)")
          row2 = $(this).find("td:eq(3)")
          row3 = $(this).find("td:eq(4)")
          row4 = $(this).find("td:eq(5)")
          css = 'color':'white', 'cursor':'default'
          notranking = "<span rel='tooltip' title='Never Ranked' class='notranking'> <b>Not Ranking</b> </span>"
          notranking_today = "<span rel='tooltip' title='Compared with today' class='notranking'> <b>Not Ranking</b> </span>"
          sortboxarrowup = "sortboxup fa fa-arrow-up"
          sortboxarrowdown = "sortboxdown fa fa-arrow-down"
          sortboxbarseq = "sortboxeq fa fa-bars"
          $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip placement: "top"
          $("#keys > tbody > tr > td.sorting_1 > a").attr
            rel: "tooltip"
            title: "View keyword data"  
          if a is 0
            if b > 0
              $("<span class='dropped' rel='tooltip' title='Compared with yesterday'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdrop").css(css).appendTo(row1)
            else
              $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Compared with yesterday' class='notranking'> <b>Not Ranking</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxeq").css(css).appendTo(row1)            
          # else if a > 0 && b is 0 && c is 0 && d is 0
            # $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Started Ranking' class='today'> <b>new</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxnew").css(css).appendTo(row1)  
          if a > b && b > 0
            $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Decreased' class='yesterday'> <b>#{a - b}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowdown).css(css).appendTo(changes)
          else if a > b && b is 0
            $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Started Ranking' class='yesterday'> <b>new</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxnew").css(css).appendTo(changes)
          else if a < b && a is 0 && b > 0
            $("<span class='yesterday' rel='tooltip' title='Dropped'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdrop").css(css).appendTo(changes)
          else if a < b
            $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Increased' class='yesterday'> <b>#{b - a}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowup).css(css).appendTo(changes)
          else if a is b
            $("<span rel='tooltip' title='No Change' class='yesterday'>  </span>").addClass(sortboxbarseq).css(css).appendTo(changes)                    
          $("select[name=keycompare]").change ->
            $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip placement: "top" 
            if $(this).val() is "1" 
              $(changes).empty() 
              if a > b && b > 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Decreased' class='yesterday'> <b>#{a - b}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowdown).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a > b && b is 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Started Ranking' class='yesterday'> <b>new</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxnew").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < b && a is 0 && b > 0
                $("<span class='yesterday' rel='tooltip' title='Dropped'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdrop").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < b
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Increased' class='yesterday'> <b>#{b - a}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowup).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a is b
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='No Change' class='yesterday'>  </span>").addClass(sortboxbarseq).css(css).appendTo(changes)
            if $(this).val() is "2"
              $(changes).empty()  
              if a > c && c > 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Decreased' class='lastweek'> <b>#{a - c}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowdown).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a > c && c is 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Started Ranking' class='lastweek'> <b>new</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxnew").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < c && a is 0 && c > 0
                $("<span class='lastweek' rel='tooltip' title='Dropped'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdrop").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < c
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Increased' class='lastweek'> <b>#{c - a}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowup).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a is c
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='No Change' class='lastweek'>  </span>").addClass(sortboxbarseq).css(css).appendTo(changes)
            if $(this).val() is "3"
              $(changes).empty() 
              if a > d && d > 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Decreased' class='lastmonth'> <b>#{a - d}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowdown).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a > d && d is 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Started Ranking' class='lastmonth'> <b>new</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxnew").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < d && a is 0 && d > 0
                $("<span class='lastmonth' rel='tooltip' title='Dropped'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdrop").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < d
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Increased' class='lastmonth'> <b>#{d - a}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowup).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a is d
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='No Change' class='lastmonth'>  </span>").addClass(sortboxbarseq).css(css).appendTo(changes) 
          return

        else if width < 1025 && width > 481
          $("select[name=keycompare] option[value='3']").remove();
          a = Number($(this).find("td")[1].innerHTML)
          b = Number($(this).find("td")[3].innerHTML)
          c = Number($(this).find("td")[4].innerHTML)
          row1 = $(this).find("td:eq(1)")
          changes = $(this).find("td:eq(2)")
          row2 = $(this).find("td:eq(3)")
          row3 = $(this).find("td:eq(4)")
          css = 'color':'white', 'cursor':'default'
          notranking = "<span rel='tooltip' title='Never Ranked' class='notranking'> <b>Not Ranking</b> </span>"
          notranking_today = "<span rel='tooltip' title='Compared with today' class='notranking'> <b>Not Ranking</b> </span>"
          sortboxarrowup = "sortboxup fa fa-arrow-up"
          sortboxarrowdown = "sortboxdown fa fa-arrow-down"
          sortboxbarseq = "sortboxeq fa fa-bars"
          $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip placement: "top"
          $("#keys > tbody > tr > td.sorting_1 > a").attr
            rel: "tooltip"
            title: "View keyword data"  
          if a is 0
            if b > 0
              $("<span class='dropped' rel='tooltip' title='Compared with yesterday'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdrop").css(css).appendTo(row1)
            else
              $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Compared with yesterday' class='notranking'> <b>Not Ranking</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxeq").css(css).appendTo(row1)            
          # else if a > 0 && b is 0 && c is 0 && d is 0
            # $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Started Ranking' class='today'> <b>new</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxnew").css(css).appendTo(row1)  
          if a > b && b > 0
            $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Decreased' class='yesterday'> <b>#{a - b}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowdown).css(css).appendTo(changes)
          else if a > b && b is 0
            $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Started Ranking' class='yesterday'> <b>new</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxnew").css(css).appendTo(changes)
          else if a < b && a is 0 && b > 0
            $("<span class='yesterday' rel='tooltip' title='Dropped'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdrop").css(css).appendTo(changes)
          else if a < b
            $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Increased' class='yesterday'> <b>#{b - a}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowup).css(css).appendTo(changes)
          else if a is b
            $("<span rel='tooltip' title='No Change' class='yesterday'>  </span>").addClass(sortboxbarseq).css(css).appendTo(changes)                    
          $("select[name=keycompare]").change ->
            $("[rel=tooltip]").tooltip placement: "top" 
            if $(this).val() is "1" 
              $(changes).empty() 
              if a > b && b > 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Decreased' class='yesterday'> <b>#{a - b}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowdown).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a > b && b is 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Started Ranking' class='yesterday'> <b>new</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxnew").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < b && a is 0 && b > 0
                $("<span class='yesterday' rel='tooltip' title='Dropped'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdrop").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < b
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Increased' class='yesterday'> <b>#{b - a}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowup).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a is b
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='No Change' class='yesterday'>  </span>").addClass(sortboxbarseq).css(css).appendTo(changes)
            if $(this).val() is "2"
              $(changes).empty()  
              if a > c && c > 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Decreased' class='lastweek'> <b>#{a - c}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowdown).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a > c && c is 0
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Started Ranking' class='lastweek'> <b>new</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxnew").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < c && a is 0 && c > 0
                $("<span class='lastweek' rel='tooltip' title='Dropped'> <b>Dropped</b> </span>").addClass("sortboxdrop").css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a < c
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='Increased' class='lastweek'> <b>#{c - a}</b> </span>").addClass(sortboxarrowup).css(css).appendTo(changes)
              else if a is c
                $("<span rel='tooltip' title='No Change' class='lastweek'>  </span>").addClass(sortboxbarseq).css(css).appendTo(changes)
          return
        else if width < 481
          $("select[name=keycompare]").remove(); 
          $(".remove-mob").remove();
      )          
    return
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't seem to have a representation of your table as data, just in the DOM.
That's making this a really cumbersome job. This will be more legible if you
follow the [Rule of Representation](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html).
Represent your table as an array of objects. Make judgements about those
objects based on their properties, and *then* render them as DOM elements.

It should go something like this:

Get your rows as data.

```coffee
# these can come from an api, database, or wherever they're coming from now
rows = [
  {today: 1, yesterday: 0, started: 0}
  {today: 2, yesterday: 4, started: 1}
  # ... etc
]
```

Add properties you need for rendering to the rows.

```coffee
computeChange = (row) ->
  [a, b] = [row.today, row.yesterday]

  if a > b and b > 0
    'decreased'
  else if a > b and b is 0
    'new'
  else if a < b and a is 0 and b > 0
    'dropped'
  else if a < b
    'increased'
  else if a is b
    'same'

# add a "change" property to each row for use in rendering
row.change = computeChange(row) for row in rows
```

You can add css classes in a similar fashion.

```coffee
cssClasses =
  decreased: 'sortboxdown fa fa-arrow-down'
  same: 'sortboxeq fa fa-bars'
  # ... etc

row.className = cssClasses[row.change] for row in rows
```

Once every row have enough information to be rendered, pass the to something
that draws rows.

```coffee
renderRow = (row) ->
  $("<span></span>").attr
    'rel': 'tooltip'
    'title': row.title
    'class': row.className

$('body').append (renderRow row for row in rows)
```

Delegate events to an element that contains everything you drew

```coffee
$('body').on 'change', 'select[name=keycompare]', (event) ->
  # event handling code here
```

Styling that you want on every element should be added to the document, not each element.

```html
<!-- in <head> -->
<style type="text/css">
  td {
    color: white;
    cursor: default;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Welcome to code review with this great answer.