# Validating a date in a grid

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, datetime, validation

This function checks if the `EndDate` of my grid is valid or not. If it is not valid, it turns the bgcolor of the cell to red color with `cell-error` class.

I need some help in optimizing this block of code. It looks dirty right now.

```
function onAccrualEndDateChange(current) {
var endDate = $(current).val();
if (endDate != "") {
    var actualEndDate = endDate;
    if (actualEndDate != null) {
        var tempEndDate = parseInt(actualEndDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + actualEndDate.getDate() + "/" + actualEndDate.getFullYear();
        if (ValidateDate(tempEndDate)) {
            var startDate = $(current).closest("tr").find("input[id$='StartDate']").val();
            if (startDate != "") {
                var actualStartDate = startDate;
                if (actualStartDate != null) {
                    var tempStartDate = parseInt(actualStartDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + actualStartDate.getDate() + "/" + actualStartDate.getFullYear();
                    if (ValidateDate(tempStartDate)) {
                        if (actualStartDate.getDate() > actualEndDate.getDate() || actualStartDate.getMonth() > actualEndDate.getMonth() || actualStartDate.getFullYear() > actualEndDate.getFullYear()) {
                            $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
                        } else {
                            $(current).closest("td").removeClass("cell-error");
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
                }
            } else {
                $(current).closest("tr").find("input[id$='StartDate']").closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
            }
        }
        else {
            $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
        }
    }
    else {
        $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
    }
} else {
    $(current).closest("td").removeClass("cell-error");
}
}
```

This is the code to validate the date:

```
function ValidateDate(date) {
//This validates date with leap year in mm/dd/yyyy or mm/d/yyyy or m/dd/yyyy or m/d/yyyy date format.
var regex = new RegExp("^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\\d)\\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$");

return (date.match(regex));
}
```

Comment: remove most of the `else` that do the same thing

Comment: But then how do I check when If conditions are not satisfied?

Comment: can add a variable `isValid=false` and change that variable along the way. Then just use one `toggleClass` at the end passing `isValid` as second argument to determine whether to add or remove class. That would likely remove most of the `else`

Answer (score 2):

This isn't "optimized", I just tried to make it more readable.
As I cant test it (really wish people would make jsbin examples to test with, buggered if Im going to do it) I have no idea if it works ;)

```
function onAccrualEndDateChange(current) {
  var endDate = $(current).val();

  if (endDate === "") {
    $(current).closest("td").removeClass("cell-error");
    return;
  }
  if (endDate === null) {
    $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
    return;
  }

  var actualEndDate = {
    month: endDate.getMonth(),
    date: endDate.getDate(),
    fullYear: endDate.getFullYear()
  };

  var tempEndDate = parseInt(actualEndDate.month + 1, 10) + "/" + actualEndDate.date + "/" + actualEndDate.fullYear;

  if (!ValidateDate(tempEndDate)) {
    $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
    return;
  }

  var startDate = $(current).closest("tr").find("input[id$='StartDate']").val();

  if (startDate === "") {
    $(current).closest("tr").find("input[id$='StartDate']").closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
    return;
  }
  if (startDate === null) {
    $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
    return;
  }

  var actualStartDate = {
    month: startDate.getMonth(),
    date: startDate.getDate(),
    fullYear: startDate.getFullYear()
  };

  var tempStartDate = parseInt(actualStartDate.month + 1, 10) + "/" + actualStartDate.date + "/" + actualStartDate.fullYear;

  if (!ValidateDate(tempStartDate)) {
    $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
    return;
  }

  if (actualStartDate.date > actualEndDate.date || actualStartDate.month > actualEndDate.month || actualStartDate.fullYear > actualEndDate.fullYear) {
    $(current).closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
  } else {
    $(current).closest("td").removeClass("cell-error");
  }
}
```

Comment: OH and do you mean undefined when you say null?....you really should check that.  Especially since I changed == to === everywhere.

Comment: I know you just made it more readable, but could you ad a little explanation to what all you did?

Comment: I basically, um, kinda, um, reversed the else's?..pffft.  I went through and recorded the results of the elses first to try and get a clue as to what was going on then re wrote it.  Heres the jsbin that I did it in.... http://jsbin.com/mewax/1/edit ... it originally had your code in the html, but thats gone now.  At the top is the working out stuff I did to figure whats going on, maybe that will help you?....sorry, but Im really not sure how to explain it :(

Answer (score 2):

Whenever possible, you should fold knowlege into data so programming logic can
be stupid and robust (this is the [Rule of Representation](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch01s06.html)). Humans are
much better at reasoning about more complex data structures than they are at
reasoning about complex logic.

You have some confusing conditions that you probably don't want. For example,
when `startDate` is an empty string, you show an error on `startInput`, but
if `startDate` is `null`, you show an error on `endInput`. Maybe that is what
you want, but you'd make it easier for a newcomer to your codebase to understand
that if you first produce the information you need to render you interface,
and *then* rendered it.

Note: it was my stylistic choice to omit semicolons and rely on automatic
semicolon insertion. I find it easier to read.

This function orchestrates the whole operation. It gets the needed elements,
clears any showing errors, checks for existing errors, and then shows errors
where appropriate.

```js
function onEndDateChange(endInput) {
  var $endInput = $(endInput)
  var $startInput = $endInput.closest("tr").find("input[id$='StartDate']")

  var errors = getErrors($startInput.val(), $endInput.val())

  hideError($endInput)
  hideError($startInput)

  if (errors.noStart || errors.invalidStart) {
    showError($startInput)
  }

  if (errors.noEnd || errors.invalidEnd || errors.anyLarger) {
    showError($endInput)
  }
}
```

This produces an `errors` object that is much more communicative than a deep
tree of `if`s and `else`s. You may want to design your error conditions
differently. For example, it's redundant here to have a `noEnd` error and an
`invalidEnd` error because an empty `end` will also fail the `invalidEnd` test.
But, if you want to use that extra information to communicate to the user
more about what is wrong, this is where you should add knowledge to the data.

```js
function getErrors (start, end) {
  var start = dateValues(start)
  var end = dateValues(end)

  var errors = {}

  function add (key) {
    errors[key] = true
  }

  if (!end) add('noEnd')
  if (!start) add('noStart')
  if (anyLarger(start, end)) add('anyLarger')
  if (!isValidDate(start)) add('invalidStart')
  if (!isValidDate(end)) add('invalidEnd')

  return errors
}
```

This elimindates some checking that was repeated frequently. Naming properites
`month`, `day`, and `year` makes the boolean questions easier to read.

```js
function dateValues (date) {
  if (!date) return null

  return {
    month: date.getMonth(),
    day: date.getDate(),
    year: date.getYear()
  }
}
```

This is the same logic you used. I think you might want to check if
`start.valueOf()` is greater than `end.valueOf()` instead of this. If this is
what you meant, here's a clearer way to write it.

```js
function anyLarger (start, end) {
  if (!start || !end) return false
  return start.day > end.day || start.month > end.month || start.year > end.year
}
```

Again, I moved parts that were getting reused into the only function that
was using them. You probably want to make this `RegExp` more legible by
breaking it into more lines and explaining what each branch does. Fat blocks
of unexplained logic tend to breed bugs.

```js
function isValidDate(obj) {
  if (!obj) return false

  var date = parseInt(obj.month + 1) + "/" + obj.day + "/" + obj.year

  // validates date with leap year
  // accepts: mm/dd/yyyy mm/d/yyyy m/dd/yyyy m/d/yyyy
  var regex = new RegExp([
    "^(((0?[1-9]|1[012])/(0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])|(0?[13456789]|1[012])/(29|30)|",
    "(0?[13578]|1[02])/31)/(19|[2-9]\\d)\\d{2}|0?2/29/((19|[2-9]\\d)(0[48]|",
    "[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(([2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))$"
  ].join(''))

  return date.match(regex)
}
```

You could (and should) swap this simple rendering logic out for a more powerful
rendering tool (like [mercury](https://github.com/Raynos/mercury) or [react](http://facebook.github.io/react/)) when your app needs
to do more things than show an error on two rows. As I said before, your life
will me much easier if you make logic and rendering really dumb functions.
Put the answers to the questions you have in the data. Pass that data to the
dumb logic/renderer.

```js
function showError (elem) {
  elem.closest("td").addClass("cell-error");
}

function hideError (elem) {
  elem.closest("td").removeClass("cell-error")
}
```

If you're looking for another example of folding knowledge into data, I wrote
a similar post [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/51293/optimize-coffeescript-comparison-function/51326#51326).

Answer (score 1):

Don't have enough context to test what you're trying to do but..

```
function onAccrualEndDateChange(current) {

        // create the jquery object once
        var $ele = $(current),
            $td = $ele.closest("td"),
            $tr = $ele.closest("tr"),
            endDate = $ele.val(),
            endDateObj, startDateObj, $startDate;

        // Empty string - remove error class
        if (endDate === "") return $td.removeClass("cell-error");

        // Falsy value - add error class
        if (! endDate) return $td.addClass("cell-error");

        // Create date object
        // String needs to be formatted acceptable to Date.parse()
        endDateObj = new Date(endDate);

        // Invalid date - add error class
        if (! endDateObj) return $td.addClass("cell-error");

        // Get the start date value
        $startDate = $tr.find("input[id$='StartDate']");

        // Empty string - add error class
        if ($startDate.val() === "") return $startDate.closest("td").addClass("cell-error");

        // Falsy value - add error class
        if (! $startDate.val()) return $td.addClass("cell-error");

        // Start date object
        var startDateObj = new Date($startDate.val());

        // invalid date - - add error class
        if (! startDateObj) return $td.addClass("cell-error");

        // start date greater than end date
        if (startDateObj.getTime() > endDateObj.getTime()){
            return $td.addClass("cell-error");
        }

        // if nothing else - remove error class
        $td.removeClass("cell-error");

}
```

This was quick and dirty and probably wont work but hopefully it helps. Keep it shallow ;)

Comment: please explain more of what you did in the code please, it makes for a better review,  glad to have you here at Code Review!